# VS2015 does not render custom window control in design view (works in VS2013)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I have a program that uses a custom window control. In VS2013 the window renders fine in design view, exactly the same solution opened in VS2015 does not. Compiles and works fine at run-time.

[image]

[image]

Snippets of relevant code are here:

```
<control:CustomWindow x:Class="CategoryView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:control="clr-namespace:ClassAccounts;assembly=ClassAccounts"
    xmlns:l="clr-namespace:WpfAccounts"
    Title="Category" Width="470" Height="485" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" OKVisibility="True">

<Window.Resources>

    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Categories}" x:Key="Categories"/>
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Headings}" x:Key="Headings"/>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="CategoryTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding comment}" Margin="0" Foreground="{Binding forecolor}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    ...
</Grid>
```

Application.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="Application"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:l="clr-namespace:WpfAccounts"
StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">

<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ClassAccounts;component/Themes/Generic.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <!-- Region SubMenu -->
        <MenuScrollingVisibilityConverter x:Key="MenuScrollingVisibilityConverter"/>

        <!-- Separator -->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Separator}" x:Key="SeparatorStyle">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CustomDarkBlue}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
                        <Rectangle Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Fill="{StaticResource CustomWhite}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

    ...

        <!-- End Region -->
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

AssemblyInfo.vb

```
Imports System
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Resources
Imports System.Windows

' General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
' set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
' associated with an assembly.

' Review the values of the assembly attributes

<Assembly: AssemblyTitle("Accounts")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyDescription("Account Program")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyCompany("")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyProduct("Accounts")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyCopyRight("Copyright ©  2013-4 Andrew Powell")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")> 
<Assembly: ComVisible(False)>

'In order to begin building localizable applications, set 
'<UICulture>CultureYouAreCodingWith</UICulture> in your .vbproj file
'inside a <PropertyGroup>.  For example, if you are using US english 
'in your source files, set the <UICulture> to "en-US".  Then uncomment the
'NeutralResourceLanguage attribute below.  Update the "en-US" in the line
'below to match the UICulture setting in the project file.

'<Assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)> 


'The ThemeInfo attribute describes where any theme specific and generic resource dictionaries can be found.
'1st parameter: where theme specific resource dictionaries are located
'(used if a resource is not found in the page, 
' or application resource dictionaries)

'2nd parameter: where the generic resource dictionary is located
'(used if a resource is not found in the page, 
'app, and any theme specific resource dictionaries)
<Assembly: ThemeInfo(ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly)> 



'The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
<Assembly: Guid("c7920515-ec57-40d4-bccb-8f5b16be77d0")> 

' Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
'
'      Major Version
'      Minor Version 
'      Build Number
'      Revision
'
' You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
' by using the '*' as shown below:
' <Assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")> 

<Assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")>
```

Generic.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ClassAccounts">

<!-- Region Colours -->

<!-- Control colors -->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomWhite" Color="White"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomDarkBlue" Color="#8DA3C1"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomGray" Color="LightGray"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomDarkHighlight" Color="#5082A4"/>
<!-- Submenu item highlight -->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomLightHighlight" Color="#3399FF"/>
<!-- TreeviewItem highlight -->
<Color x:Key="CustomLightHighlightC" A="#FF" R="#33" G="#99" B="#FF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomBackground" Color="#B5CBEF"/>
<Color x:Key="CustomBackgroundC" A="#FF" R="#B5" G="#CB" B="#EF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomHighlightedControlGlyph" Color="#3C7FB1"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomHighlightedControlBorder" Color="#222"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomPressedControlGlyph" Color="#003366"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomPressedControlBorder" Color="#526C7B"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomPressedControlBackground" Color="#595959"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomGlyph" Color="#444"/>

<!-- Window Colors -->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomWindowBorder" Color="#395984"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomHeaderLight" Color="#E7EBF7"/>
<Color x:Key="CustomHeaderLightC" A="#FF" R="#E7" G="#EB" B="#F7"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomHeaderDark" Color="#CEE3FF"/>
<Color x:Key="CustomHeaderDarkC" A="#FF" R="#CE" G="#E3" B="#FF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomControl" Color="Gray"/>

<!-- End Region -->

<!-- Region Window -->

<!-- Window Button style -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="WindowButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Webdings"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource CustomControl}"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
                <Border x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Margin="0" Padding="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<!-- Window style -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomWindow}" x:Key="{x:Type local:CustomWindow}">
    <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None"/>
    <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="NoResize"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ShowInTaskbar" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Icon" Value="\coins.ico"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomWindow}">
                <Border Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Name="windowFrame" BorderBrush="{StaticResource CustomWindowBorder}" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="0,20,20,20">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush>
                            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                <GradientStopCollection>
                                    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource CustomHeaderLightC}" Offset="0.0"></GradientStop>
                                    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource CustomHeaderDarkC}" Offset="0.25"></GradientStop>
                                </GradientStopCollection>
                            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Border.Background>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" x:Name="tbTitle" Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" FontSize="14" Margin="0" Padding="4"/>
                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5,15,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Transparent">
                                <Button x:Name="RefreshButton" Content="q" Style="{StaticResource WindowButtonStyle}"/>
                                <Button x:Name="MinimizeButton" Content="0" Style="{StaticResource WindowButtonStyle}"/>
                                <Button x:Name="OKButton" Content="a" Style="{StaticResource WindowButtonStyle}" IsDefault="True"/>
                                <Button x:Name="CloseButton" Content="r" Style="{StaticResource WindowButtonStyle}" IsCancel="True"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid x:Name="grdMain" Grid.Row="1" Background="{StaticResource CustomBackground}">
                            <AdornerDecorator>
                                <ContentPresenter/>
                            </AdornerDecorator>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="15,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="tbStatusLeft" FontSize="14" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="150" Padding="2"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="tbStatusLeft2" FontSize="14" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="150" Padding="2"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="tbStatusLeft3" FontSize="14" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="150" Padding="2"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <Canvas x:Name="canStatusMiddle" Grid.Column="1" ClipToBounds="True">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="tbStatusMiddle" FontSize="14" Margin="0,0,0,0" Padding="2" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Canvas>
                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,15,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="tbStatusRight3" FontSize="14" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="150" Padding="2" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="tbStatusRight2" FontSize="14" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="150" Padding="2" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="tbStatusRight" FontSize="14" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="150" Padding="2" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="OKVisibility" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="OKButton" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="RefreshVisibility" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="RefreshButton" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="ExtraStatus" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="tbStatusLeft2" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="tbStatusLeft3" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="tbStatusRight2" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="tbStatusRight3" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!-- End Region-->
```

Sample project - https://www.sendspace.com/file/z4a4tg

Any help gratefully appreciated.
Andy

Comment: Do you have any blue squiggles in any of your xaml files? Everything works at runtime?

Comment: Works fine at runtime. Thanks (edited main post)

Comment: No blue squiggles if you open up all your XAML files in 2015? 2015 shows errors that previous versions didn't. I would assume that it didn't pick up the window style itself, but it did pick up all the other styles is that you have some error in your window style that 2013 didn't care about, but 2015 does.

Comment: No blue squiggles. It has to be something to do with the ResourceDictionary - as the controls you can see are defined in Application.xaml but the custom window itself is in Generic.xaml. BUT it compiles and runs completely fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have discovered a couple of things. I note in the example project I posted that actually it doesn't render properly in VS2013. The key line from Generic.xaml is this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomWindow}" x:Key="{x:Type local:CustomWindow}">
```

If I change it to:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomWindow}">
```

It renders fine in VS2013 (but still not in VS2015). In theory (from MSDN) this should not make a difference as x:Key is implicit if not specified.

> As shown in the first example above, setting the TargetType property to TextBlock without assigning the style with an x:Key allows your style to be applied to all TextBlock elements. What actually happens is that doing so implicitly sets the x:Key to {x:Type TextBlock}. This also means that if you give the Style an x:Key value of anything other than {x:Type TextBlock}, the Style would not be applied to all TextBlock elements automatically. Instead, you need to apply the style to the TextBlock elements explicitly.

(from https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms745683(v=VS.85).aspx#styling_targettype)

What does seem to fix it in VS2015 (although its a little bit of a fudge) is changing it to:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomWindow}" x:Key="CustomWindow">
```

and adding

```
<Style="{DynamicResource CustomWindow}">
```

to each window xaml in the main project. I don't think I should have to do this, and I think there might be a bug in both VS2013 and VS2015 as really either of the first two should work.

Grateful for any thoughts and thanks for input so far.
Andy

Comment: You, Sir, are my new hero. I struggled for 3 days on this, reducing a mountain of code with more than 5 base libraries to just `Generic`, `App` and `MainWindow` xaml files (with a little code-behind). After still not having any luck, I stumbled across your suggestion and **voila**, it works!

Answer (score 1):

I am doing something similar to you and mine is working fine in VS2015, I see my styled window in the designer. Mine is set up SLIGHTLY different though.

App.Xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/xxx.yyy;component/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Notice the different path syntax. I'm mentioning this because I had the opposite issue on a control. For some reason, in one window the designer would not pick up resources that used the /xxx.yyy;component syntax. When I switched it over to pack syntax, the designer was able to see the resources.

Like I said, I have a custom window (frame, client, everything is overriden) as well. The designer is showing the styled version.

Also, my generic.xaml is similiar. It just includes the other xaml files:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/xxx.yyy;component/Themes/xxxWindow.xaml" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ClassAccounts;component/Themes/Generic.xaml"/> and <ResourceDictionary Source="/ClassAccounts;component/Themes/Generic.xaml"/> and <ResourceDictionary Source="../ClassAccounts;component/Themes/Generic.xaml"/> all without success (ie compile/run fine but not show in designer)

Comment: Hmm... are you using a key for the style? Or global style? Are you doing any initialization in code behind? Any ifdefs or InDesignMode type checks? There isn't really any way to debug design time issues as far as I know... you might have to contact Microsoft.

Comment: Hi. Gobal style (I have added Generic.xaml to the question above). There is some code in OnApplyTemplate to add handlers to some controls on the window, nothing else. No ifdefs etc.. I have posted a bug report to Microsoft. Thanks.

Comment: Sample project that reproduces added to initial post

Comment: I tried your project and I see the same issue. I tried commenting out a bunch of stuff and just setting the window background color in the app.xaml and it doesn't get picked up by the designer. If I put it in the window.resources, it gets picked up. So I'm gonna say its a Vb.net only issue because it works in C# :). My code is C# and the designer picks up styles from everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for looking. I uploaded the same project to Microsoft so we'll see what they say and I'll feedback here.

Comment: Upvote, mine is because of the "Generic.xaml" is not defined in App.xaml. (But it still compiles tho..) So I added it back and now the Control is rendering now:)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with VS 2015 Update 2. I installed Update 3 and it resolved the problem.